# Using "Max" summary in pivot table for data organized by non numerical hierarchy (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table, tabular

In SheetA I've got a set of rows that have a "Rating Of Thing" column.
[image: A snapshot of SheetA. (The "Range Order" column is not part of the table in questions, but is used for the purposes of illustration to show the hierarchy of the things in the "Rating of Thing" column]

The rating of thing column assigns ratings that belong to a non-numerical hierarchy. On a separate sheet (SheetB), using a pivot table, I'd like to display certain items in that sheet based on their position in that hierarchy. However, since the "Rating Of Thing" list is non-numerical, I'm getting results like the following.
[image: I get zero's for the ratings that are non-numeerical]

I'd like to know how to create some sort of "on the go" mapping when the pivot table handles the "Rating of Thing" column so that I can find the max or highest rating for each month and display it in the table.

Link to the live sheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mI6kmxvibHebAsQG-UFTLw7jgjjIzG_oLk3eq2i0u_Q/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: added a link at the bottom @player0

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(""&SORTN(SORT({TEXT(MONTH(A2:A&1), "00")&"×"&A2:A, C2:C}, 
 MATCH(C2:C, E2:E5, 0), 1), 9^9, 2, 1, 1), ".*×", ))
```

[image]